# Fullscreen spaces insist on always opening new windows on the desktop furthest away (desktop 1)

Tags: mojave, desktop, window-manager, spaces

I currently have these spaces:

```
[Desktop 1] [Eight other spaces including three desktops] [Fullscreen browser]
```

...and started noticing that even when I'm in the Fullscreen Browser space and I open a new window, e.g. using Dock to open a non-running application, or by opening a downloaded file, they all spawn on Desktop 1. This results in one very cluttered desktop full of windows, and three unused desktops. I also can't quickly swipe my way back to the fullscreen browser.

Is there a reason why the windows don't appear on the closest desktop? I'd prefer to be thrown away as short a distance as possible, if possible. Can this be changed somehow?

I know it's not part of the "restore windows from previous session" feature, since it also happens even when I explicitly select "open new window" from Dock, for e.g. Finder or Safari.

*macOS 10.14*

Comment: I'm not understanding "Eight other spaces including three desktops" Apple uses the terms Space & Desktop interchangeably [unfortunately] so how are you differentiating?

Comment: @Tetsujin oh sorry, I always thought Apple consistently use the word space when referring to desktops or full screen apps, while reserving the word desktop exclusively for desktops. That's what I meant anyway.

Comment: Basically, fullscreen was & remains badly thought-out & poorly implemented. I never use it  because of its serious failings. I have always been a big advocate of Spaces though, as a concept. Spaces are numbered & can be recalled at will, fullscreens have no shortcut structure at all, except 'swipe through one at a time'.